# Como puedo recoger de una tabla datos de una plantilla html y enviarlo a otra plantilla html para visualizar

Tags: html, python, postgresql, flask, checkbox

tengo un problema con codigo html.

Tengo este código html

```
<form action="{{url_for('exportar')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sortable" id="parts-table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th id="selection-state-head"><input type="checkbox" role="button" onclick="selectAllRows(this)" style="margin:10%;"></th>
                        <th class="sortable both" role="button" scope="col" id="date-head">Fecha</th>
                        <th scope="col">Dedicación</th>
                        <th class="sortable both" role="button" scope="col" id="type-head">Tipo de tarea</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estado de tarea</th>
                        <th class="sortable both" role="button" id="employee-head" scope="col">Técnico</th>
                        <th class="sortable both" role="button" id="customer-head" scope="col">Cliente</th>
                        <th id="work-head" scope="col">Tarea</th>
                        <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                        {% if g.employee %}
                        <th id="edit-btn-head" scope="col">Ver/Editar</th>
                        {% endif %}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                        {%for line in lines%}
                            <tr>
                                <td class="selection-state">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" role="button"  style="margin:10%;" id="{{ line.id }}">
                                </td>
                                <td id="line_date" scope="row" style="width: 100px">{{ line.fecha }}</td>
                                <td id="line_duration" >{{ (line.dedicacion|string)[:-3] }}</td>
                                <td id="line_work-type" style="width: 140px">{{ line.tipo_tarea}}</td>
                                <td id="line_status"  style="width: 140px">{{ line.estado_tarea}}</td>
                                <td id="line_employee">{{ line.tecnico}}</td>
                                <td id="line_party" >{{ line.cliente}}</td>
                                <td id="line_work" >{{ line.tarea }}</td>
                                <td id="line_description">{{ line.descripcion }}</td>
                                <td id="line_internal-description" style="display:none;">{{ line.editor_ver }}</td>
                                {% if g.employee %}
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="edit-btn btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                        <tr id="time-count" style="height: 35px;" colspan="10">
                            <td></td><td></td>
                            <td id="time-cell"></td>
                            <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                            {% if g.employee %}
                            <td></td>
                            {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                        <button type="submit">Exportar</button>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto flask, tengo definida una función que lo que hace es que recoge toda la línea de registros de esa posición de la tabla para luego poder enviarla a otra plantilla html para visualización y posterior tratamiento.

```
@app.route('/exportar', methods=['POST'])
def exportar():
    print('llega')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        datos_checkbox = request.form.getlist('checkbox')
        return render_template('exportar_excel.html', prueba=datos_checkbox)
    return render_template('exportar.html')
```

El problema que me estoy encontrando es que al ejecutar la app lo que me está imprimiendo en la plantilla html es 'on'.

Este 'on' es que funciona el checkbox, pero no me está recogiendo la información que yo queria.

Answer (score 0):

Al final la solución que he encontrado es esta:

```
<td class="selection-state">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" onclick="selectRow(this)" role="button"  style="margin:10%;"  value="{{line.id}}">
</td>
```

Lo que he hecho es poner al final value="{{line.id}}", lo que le estoy pasando es el id de la tabla, por lo que, luego en la función de flask puedo sacar el resto de campos de este id en cuestión.